# Is linux is good at video processing?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu

I tried running a 4k video (streamed from Youtube) in Linux and Windows using Firefox. I found that in Windows it is not playing well (it is just like watching images) while in Ubuntu 14.04 it runs smoothly. Does this really means Windows is bad at video processing? I have the following graphics card: Ati sunpro 8570m. In Windows I installed the proprietary driver while in Ubuntu I used the open source driver. Does this difference in frame rate occur because the open source driver outperforms the proprietary driver? My laptop specs are:

- Intel Corei5 3230m
- 8gb ram
- 2gb 8570m graphics card

Comment: Given this huge difference in performance you can't say Linux is better than Windows for this task. This sounds more like mis-configured drivers (as you already hint). Which Windows version do you use? Windows 7? 8?

Comment: i use windows 7

Answer (score -2):

If the player was html5 player than probably Linux is better choice as it is free operating system, but especially in the past Linux had bad support for YouTube as it mostly run on adobe flash plug-in.